# (GraphQL) - Why does Apollo check the cache first, before doing anything else?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

We are developing APIs using Apollo GraphQL. We use the out of the box caching solution that Apollo provides (`KeyValueCache` using a Redis datastore).

When a request query arrives, why does ApolloServer check the cache first before it does anything else?

Is there any way to insert logic before the cache is touched? For example, we want to do some authentication and permissions checking before Apollo checks the cache.

(Yes, there are directives but we find `Public/Private` scope and `maxAge` insufficient for our needs.)

Answer (score 0):

The code and explanation below flags a few different approaches for you to explore -- hopefully one will suit your needs (I am assuming you know you can control whether Apollo looks to cache first by `fetchPolicy` - although I discuss this briefly below). First, consider using a HOC that checks permissions and authentication prior to returning the passed Component. The permissions/auth data can be passed as props should the passed Component be rendered.

```
withUserData = Component => {
  const { isValidated, userData } = checkAuthAndPermissions(); // Modify for your implementation 
  if (!isValidated) return null;
  return <Component userData={userData} />
}
```

You can thereafter wrap any Component that needs to make the auth/permission check with the HOC, as shown below. As also shown below, Apollo provides the opportunity to skip the query altogether looking to props or other logic, if that is something you may consider. Finally, through the option prop, you have the ability to set the fetchPolicy, which could be dynamically based on a permission check or props. With this fetchPolicy you could avoid looking to cache if that is an objective.

```
const ComponentWithApollo = graphql(YOUR_QUERY, {
  skip: props => { /* consider permissions/auth here, skip if needed */ },
  options: props => {
    const fetchPolicy = determineFetchPolicyFromAuthOrPermissions(); 
    return { fetchPolicy };
  },
  props: ({ data }) => data
})(YourComponent);

withUserData(ComponentWithApollo);
```